# Placing a device model in a Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I need to print my device's model in a Text widget.

I tried using the FutureBuilder widget to get the device model.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';

class DeviceInfoPage extends StatelessWidget {
  String s;
  Future _getModel() async{
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    return androidInfo.model;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _getModel(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
              if(snap.hasData) {}
              else {}
            }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the `androidInfo.model` string from the `_getModel` method. I understand that the return type is Future, so I tried using a future builder to get the value.  But now I'm at a loss.  Trying `_getModel().then(value)` won't work, so I don't know how to extract the device model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the snap parameter. I suppose you can do something like:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _getModel(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snap) {
      if(snap.hasData) {
        Text('Model: ${snap.data}')
      } else {
        Text('Awaiting model...')
      }
    }
),
```

The recommended is to check the connection state. Check the [docs example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for more information and maybe refactor to something like that:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: _getModel(), 
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text('Awaiting result...');
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
    return null;
  },
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help! -